# Using int values from arrays - c#

Tags: c#

I am making a program that calculates energy usage. I have created a single dimensional integer array that stores the power ratings for each of the appliances on the program. When the user clicks on a checkbox I want to get the 1st element of the array and use it in a calculation.
What code needs to go in the checkbox method?
Also, how do I convert the `int` values to `string` so I can print them in a textbox?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    int[] AppliancePower = new int[3];
    AppliancePower[0] = 5000;
    AppliancePower[1] = 4000;
    AppliancePower[2] = 7000;
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
public class Form1
{
    private int[] AppliancePower = new[]
    {
        5000,
        4000,
        7000
    };

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            var value = AppliancePower[0];
            DoSomeFanyCalculation(value);
            this.textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I get the error "The name 'AppliancePower' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Set your array as a field for the class rather than a local variable in the constructor :)

Comment: In your example you create a local variable in the constructor and never assig it. Make it a global variable inside Form1 (I updated my answer)

Comment: Please be precise, this is and should not be a _global_ variable but a class **member** variable.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easy.

```
public class Form1
{
    public int[] AppliancePower;
    public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();

         AppliancePower = new int[3];
         AppliancePower[0] = 5000;
         AppliancePower[1] = 4000;
         AppliancePower[2] = 7000;
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(AppliancePower.Length > 0)
       {
            int FirstValue = AppliancePower[0];
            string StringValue = FirstValue .ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error "The name 'AppliancePower' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @MichaelRoberts You need to declare it as public

Comment: How? (new to this, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what the other 2 answer suggested, or you can save a step and just do this:

```
this.textBox1.Text = (checkBox1.Checked) ? AppliancePower[0].ToString() : string.Empty ;
```

Also, you need to declare the AppliancePower on the class level, and not in your constructor:

```
// class level:
int[] AppliancePower;

public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();

AppliancePower = new int[3];
AppliancePower[0] = 5000;
AppliancePower[1] = 4000;
AppliancePower[2] = 7000;
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = (checkBox1.Checked) ? AppliancePower[0].ToString() : string.Empty ;

}
```

Comment: I get the error "The name 'AppliancePower' does not exist in the current context". Do I need to declare 'AppliancePower' somewhere in the code?